# How to switch to MongoDB after MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database

Let's imagine I have MySQL DB with:
1000 users in table Users

```
ID | Name
1  | user 1
...
n  | user n
```

200 000 instruments in table Instruments

```
ID | Name
1  | instr 1
   ...
n  | instr n
```

And more than 1 million orders in table Orders

```
ID | Name    | User ID | Instrument ID
1  | instr 1 |   1     |       1
   ...
n  | instr n |   n     |       n
```

Tell me please, How to design this in MongoDB?

Comment: Why switch to a database system you don't know using....

Comment: What's wrong with MySQL?  It can store that data easily enough.  You have not said what processing you will be doing.

Comment: Hello! I just learn MongoDB and want to know how it's will be look at Mongo.

Comment: What it looks like is how you actually create it. What you have here is a "relational model" and MongoDB is not really designed for relational purposes. Rather it's actual intent is for application spaces that do not fit will into a relational design. So you "could" simply use the exact same relational model, **but** you probably "should not". More to the point is that you "should" be aware of why you want to use MongoDB and therefore have some idea of what the structure should look like there. Can you just migrate? Yes! Should you? No. Redesign on stay on relational.